# Javascript - how to reference a callback from string/object

Tags: javascript

This code isn't working since it seems I declared an object with attributes. How to have it working and reference the callback from the string/object I pass?

```
var HttpDispatcher = function() {
  this.listeners = { get: [ ], post: [ ] }; 
} 

HttpDispatcher.prototype.on = function(method, url, cb) {

  this.listeners[method].push({
    cb: cb,
    url: url 
  }); 
}

var obj = new HttpDispatcher();
obj.on("get", "page1", function() {document.write("hello");});

document.write(obj.listeners["get"]["page1"]()); // won't work for "page1"
```

Comment: `obj.listeners["get"]` is an array, so `obj.listeners["get"][0]` ...

Comment: By using `.push()`, you're making `this.listeners[method]` an array aren't you? So you're pushing an array element that is an object with the callback function and the url in it.

Comment: Like @Musa and @Jonathan stated you're trying to access an array `obj.listeners['get'][0].url` returns page1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
HttpDispatcher.prototype.on = function(method, url, cb) {

  this.listeners[method][url]=cb;
}
```

This would allow you to call it as you did:

```
document.write(obj.listeners["get"]["page1"]());
```

Your current code is pushing into an array an element containing an object that has both the callback and url in it.

Comment: This makes sense to me — using `obj.listeners['get'][0]` to access a callback doesn't work well in practice.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do but I got it wrong. Thanks!